# IntelliJ hangs on right-click in/on file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Context: In a Scala project, using ScalaTest, right clicking a test file to run it will caude IntelliJ to hang (cursor stops flickering). If I left click somewhere, it will be fine but the menu doesn't come up. Even after waiting a minute, it just stops hanging and the menu doesn't come up. Have to usually go through multiple cycles in order to run the file. Adding the run configuration and running that manually works.
I'm on version 2017.2.1

Comment: It looks like it should have been a bug report for IntelliJ.

Comment: Please raise a bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL